# Python yfinance stock data download stopped working a couple of hours ago

Tags: python, yfinance

I wrote a Python program that uses yfinance. The program was working fine until a couple of hours ago. I isolated it to the 4 instructions below. Other statements such as "print (symbol.info)" do work. Only data download stopped working. Can someone try and tell me if the code below works for him? Thanks.

```
import yfinance
symbol = "NFLX"
data = yfinance.download(symbol,'2019-1-1','2021-1-6')
print (data)
```

Comment: Can you add the error message you are getting to your question?

Comment: The error is very long. Here is the start of it:

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

Comment: Post the **full** error message **in the question**.  This will help to determine what is going wrong.  We can edit it later if it's too long.

Comment: The Stack overflow does not let you post more than a specific number of characters. The error message exceeds this number. If you run the code, you will see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found and fixed the problem.
Apparently, yfinance came with a new version today 0.1.62 that fixed the problem.

I installed the new version using the command prompt and everything works fine now.

pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir